# Future Xubuntu updates after the three year LTS period?

Tags: xubuntu, release-management

I started using Ubuntu two years ago by installing the Xubuntu 9.04 and then 
proceeded to install Gnome and a selection of extra packages I needed.

I am forced to migrate to a new version since 9.04 is no longer supported.

I was planning on installing Xubuntu 12.04 mainly for the LTS feature thinking 
that it would be supported for 5 years much like the standard version. 
However Xubuntu is only supported for 3 years.

My Questions:

1. With standard Ubuntu 12.04, could one resort to a simpler / more traditional look
   than Gnome Unity? 
   If so will the rest of the installed packages and functionality remain usable and
   functional?
2. Could one resort to installing Xubuntu 12.04 instead and add extra packages
   from the repository as needed?
3. Am I right in assuming that Xubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.04 share the same
   repository? In which case:

   1. Why/how is it said that Xubuntu 12.04 has support for 3 years versus 
        the 5 years support offered for Ubuntu 12.04?
   2. Could an Xubuntu 12.04 installation continue upgrading from the 12.04 
        (Precise Pangolin) repositories with given that they ought to be 
        around for 5 years to honour the commitment to standard Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Xubuntu 12.04 is light as compared to kubuntu or ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a new way of providing LTS, by allowing each flavor to decidee the length of support, all the details may have to wait three years. However, under the 3/5 year support plan, anything Xfce specific will no longer be updated or fixed after three years. Also, bug reports will no longer be accepted after three years.

I do not know if the developers will attempt to determine the desktop package, and only allow certain systems to have updates, or if some updates will be allowed for everyone for five years.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, kind of confirms my own hunch and guesses

Answer (score 2):

Well seeing that LTS releases come out every 2 years (ex:10.04/12.04), three years is not really that bad. You can upgrade in three years and get another three years support. Sticking with an operating system after three years, is really not that beneficial. Allot of LTS users usually upgrade when next LTS comes out. Xubuntu 14.04 should be next LTS release.